# The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder: The getter 'email' was called on null. in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

in my code when I pressed the register it shows the error. when I remove the navigator and print something it is printing and in my firebase authentication, I saw my emails. 
[error massage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frwUm.png)

```
TextEditingController email = new TextEditingController();
TextEditingController pass = new TextEditingController();

//  String email;
//  String password;

press: () async {

//                print(email);
//                print(password);
//                  try {
//                    final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
//                        email: email.trim(), password: password.trim());
//                    if (newUser != null) {
//                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatScreen.id);
//                    }
//                  } catch (e) {
//                    print(e);
//                  }

                  AuthResult user;
                  try {
                    user = (await mauth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                      email: email.text.trim(),
                      password: pass.text.trim(),
                    ));
                    print("ok");
                  } catch (e) {
                    print(e);
                  } finally {
                    if (user != null) {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatScreen.id);
                      //print('sing up ');
                    }
                  }
                },
```

Comment: Where are u using email?

Comment: Please add your complete code, and delete all the commented code, so it doesn't confuse

Comment: https://gist.github.com/shafinr23/99d3599760373d327ad126cfc4ccb068

Answer (score 0):

You can add a default email or empty text if email is null

```
TextField(
  controller: email ?? '',
  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
    hintText: ' Enter your Email',
  ),
),
```